# Rename files giving an increased numeric value based on previous occurrences, using bash

Tags: linux, bash, batch-rename

The answer **that worked for me** and provided the most flexibility is by @M.NejatAydin:

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd "$1" || exit

FQPATH=$1
OUTPATH=$2
rm $OUTPATH/*
for src in $FQPATH/[^0-9]*.fastq.gz; do
        FILENAME=${src##*/}
        dst=${FILENAME#*_}
        while [[ -e "$OUTPATH/$dst" ]]; do
                n=${dst#*_S}
                n=$(( ${n%%_*} + 1 ))
                dst=${dst%%S*}S${n}_${dst#*_*_}
        done
        echo "cp -s  "$src" "$FQPATH/ren/$dst""
        cp -s  "$src" "$FQPATH/ren/$dst"
echo 'END'
done
```

**What I wanted**

I have the following filenames in a folder:

```
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124771_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124771_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124771_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124771_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124771_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124771_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Those have the following characteristics:

```
identifier_sampleName(integer)_S[1-100]_R[1-3]_001.fastq.gz
```

separated by `_`.

In a following step the `$identifier` will be deleted the filename will be trimmed to:

```
124771_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

The problem comes from the possibility of some of those entries to end up with identical filename:

```
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

**What I want is**

```
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz --> 124769_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

When there are just a few samples I am using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

 for i in $1/A006850080*.fastq.gz
do
 DIR=${i%/*}
 base1=${i##*/}
 NOEXT=${base1%.*}
 NOEXT1=${NOEXT%.*}
    
 A="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f1)"
 B="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f2)"
 C="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f3)"
 D="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f4)"
 E="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f5)"
 F="$(echo $NOEXT1 | cut -d'_' -f6)"

SNUM=(${C:1})
NUM=$((SNUM+1))
mv $DIR/$base1 $DIR/$A"_"$B"_S"$NUM"_"$D"_"$E"_"$F".fastq.gz"
done
```

`NUM=$((SNUM+1))`: in this line I have counted the occurrences of the A006200089_124769* filename and increased the S[1-100] part by that number.

This code is not enough if

- more occurrences will be there:

  ```
    A006850069_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
    A006850075_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 
    A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz 
    A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
  ```
- more `$sampleName` (could be in the range of 100s)

Is there a way to parse all files of the same `$sampleName` and change the S[1-100] part so that no files will be overwritten?

Thank you in advance

Comment: using bash substitution modes within the filenames in a while loop on reading list of filenames  /  or with sed if you prefer it or even rename commands. you can test in /tmp with structure like `for i in $(seq 1 3); do touch 006850069_124769_S1_L$i._R1_001.fastq.gz; done` etc ... to test without errors

Comment: thank you for your fast response,
could you please give an example?
can the while syntax provide increment of the S[1-100] part?
for some reason I can not figure out a way. I am sure it is simpler than I think but I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation in plain bash:
`$ cat /tmp/rename`

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1" || exit

for src in [^0-9]*.fastq.gz; do
    dst=${src#*_}
    while [[ -e $dst ]]; do
        n=${dst#*_S}
        n=$(( ${n%%_*} + 1 ))
        dst=${dst%%S*}S${n}_${dst#*_*_}
    done
    mv  ./"$src" ./"$dst"
done
```

Test:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ touch A00620008{0,9}_124769_S1_L00{1,2}_R{1,2}_001.fastq.gz
$ ls -1
A006200080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200080_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006200080_124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200080_124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
$ /tmp/rename /tmp/test
$ ls -1
124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
124769_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
124769_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
124769_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
124769_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

Comment: here again 
do not it twice on same directory - it wil use the new names underscores and rename again to S1_L001_R1_011.fastq.gz at first & L001_R1_001.fastq.gz and so on... but it is a very elegant way to do that

Comment: @francoisP Fair enough. Added a `[^0-9]` to the pattern so that the filenames that begin with a digit (already renamed files) won't match.

Comment: It also gives me an error:
A. the first file is copied successfully
running command: cp -s testrename/A006200078_124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz testrename/ren/124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
B. but then:
running command: cp -s testrename/A006200079_124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz testrename/ren/124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/home/hthiele0/testrename/ren/124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz' to '/home/hthiele0/testrename/A006200079_124778_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz': File exists

Comment: @sunta3iouxos symbolic links don't work like that. You are trying to do a different thing than that of your question.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, do you maybe have a work around?
I also do not really why it will not work? I am using the cp, which works like mv (not really since if the file is in the same partition the file will only have a different header(?)) so adding the -s in the man page states that it will work as an cp but creating a symlink instead.

Comment: @sunta3iouxos Either update your question properly or ask a new question. I wouldn't answer to a non-existent question. The symlink created by the `cp` could be a dangling symlink if you used it like that.

Comment: well I just did it with mv as you stated and it doesn't work.
originally I had 96 files (of course dummy ones) end up with 48. I create the files with : touch A00620007{8..9}_1247{7..8}{8..9}_S1_L00{1..4}_R{1..3}_001.fastq.gz

Comment: @sunta3iouxos It works for me, I end up with 96 files. Or you want a different thing that I couldn't understand.

Comment: @sunta3iouxos I've added a test case to my answer. Is it the output that you expect?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Now it works, I've seen that the script reads the existing folder for entries of 124769_S* and then does the appropriate counting (this is why redirection does not work with the cp). That means that if I want to restart the sript I need to firstly clean the previous entries!
I would love it if you could provide a short explanation, for future reference. I am not really understand the first: "[^0-9]*.fastq.gz; do". this would recognize anything that starts with a number and end with fastq.gz, but it appears that it recognises also the A part?
Thank you

Comment: @sunta3iouxos The `^` in `[^0-9]` means `not`. So, `[^0-9]*.fastq.gz` means; anything that does *not* begin with a digit and ends with `.fastq.gz`.

Comment: thought starts with. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 2):

One more way to do it...

```
for f in A*.fastq.gz;             # edited for idempotence
do new=${f#*_};                   # remove the leading field
   i=1;                           # initialize the version counter
   while [[ -e "$new" ]];         # while the new filename already exists
   do printf -v n %03d $((++i));  # increment and format the counter
      new=${new%_*}_$n.fastq.gz;  # and use it in the new filename
   done;                          # will exit when it finds an unused name
   mv $f $new;                    # and move the file to that name
done
```

Comment: do not it twice on same directory - it wil use the new names underscores and rename again to S1_L001_R1_011.fastq.gz at first & L001_R1_001.fastq.gz and so on...

Comment: this does not work for me the output is:
file before change as set in line 2 124789_S1_L004_R3_001.fastq.gz
file after change: 124789_S1_L004_R3_001.fastq.gz
it is as if the while does not work

Comment: while [[ -e "$new" ]] checks to see if the file is already there - if it is, it will make a new name and leave the old file alone. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Ah. I'm incrementing the wrong field. . . Principle is the same and another answer has been accepted, so I'll leave it as a variant. Let me know if anyone actually wants me to change it to what the OP actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you might work around that :

```
#!/bin/bash
#-xe for debug

# to adapt this is not the solution but a minimal work around

count=0
set -- *.gz
while (($#)); do
        mv -- "${1}" $(echo ${1} | sed 's/^[A-Z][0-9]\{9\}_//;s/L.../L'$(printf "%03d" ${count})'/')
        shift
        count=$(( count + 1))
done
```

you should add at least a condition if file exist or better an error message management just before applying the `mv` command.

how it works is substitution of useless name part starting by A & 9 zeros & underscore by nothing & then it substitute L follow by 3 characters by L and a formatted counting number

number increases of course
formatting counter is necessary to avoid getting   a1.txt instead of a001.txt

of course this is not a full solution you have to adapt it to your needs.

```
# ls
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  A006200089_124771_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124771_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  test.sh
A006200089_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124769_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124771_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
A006200089_124771_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124771_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  A006850080_124771_S2_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
# ./test.sh 
# ls -lrth 
total 4.0K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 257 Jul 24 19:02 test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L000_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L009_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124769_S1_L005_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L011_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jul 24 19:17 124771_S2_L010_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

consider also using many variable instead of a long sub-command in the sed applied here

Comment: yes but it was the easiest way to explain a method of substitution

Comment: Him could you please give a bit more info on your reasoning for using shift and set --?
Also I updated a bit the subject to reflect a more viable solution since I can not just increase without a specific rule the numbering. The follwoing analysis might work with the last numeric part changed (might ignore it) but I've never test it.